# Is time() independent of time zone settings?

Tags: php, time, timezone

I know the time zone can be changed by the following methods (and maybe more):

1. Set `putenv()` with the time zone in every php file.
2. Set `date.timezone` with the time zone in php.ini.
3. Set `php_value date.timezone` with the time zone in the root .htaccess file.

My question is, does setting the time zone only affect the `date()` function, or does it also affect the `time()` function?

I read the documentation, but I'm still a little confused.. I *think* the answer is the former, but I need to make sure, so it would be great if someone could confirm this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

time() isn't affected by timezone. functions like date, convert the resulting date to the timezone without affecting the timestamp.

```
<?php
var_dump(date_default_timezone_get());

$time1 = time();
var_dump($time1);
var_dump(date("r", $time1));

date_default_timezone_set("America/Los_Angeles");
var_dump(date_default_timezone_get());

$time2 = time();
var_dump($time2);
var_dump(date("r", $time1));

var_dump($time1 === $time2);
```

Outputs:

```
string(16) "Europe/Amsterdam"
int(1571676424)
string(31) "Mon, 21 Oct 2019 18:47:04 +0200"
string(19) "America/Los_Angeles"
int(1571676424)
string(31) "Mon, 21 Oct 2019 09:47:04 -0700"
bool(true)
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/Cggc3

Answer (score 3):

Try the following example :

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Paris");
echo gmdate("H:i:s");
echo "<br/>";
echo date("H:i:s");
echo "<br/>";
echo time();

echo "<br/>";
echo "<br/>";

date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Chungking");
echo gmdate("H:i:s");
echo "<br/>";
echo date("H:i:s");
echo "<br/>";
echo time();

echo "<br/>";
echo "<br/>";
```

Displays :

```
18:52:38
19:52:38
1354647158

18:52:38
02:52:38
1354647159
```

Answer (score 3):

> Returns the current time measured in the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT).

Since this is an absolute point in time, the seconds elapsed since then are (except for relativistic purposes) is unambigous. You will get the same value regardless of any timezone setting.

Answer (score 2):

php time() calculate the time using GMT so it is independent of what you set the timezone